# Why jQuery removes Margin when showing/hiding the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, margin

I have an element that has margin-top and border. When I call `$(element).show()` it doesn't use the element's margin and the it doesn't look good (in [original fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadalli/SYaZh/1/) If you click on the div that is after the input text the slide animate starts from top of the text input and you see a black line passing it and it's not beautiful! I want the animate start form the bottom of the text input.)

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadalli/SYaZh/4/) is my beta in jsFiddle. but The [orginal](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadalli/SYaZh/1/) is diffrent (I remove an element because the wanted element cannot be found!)

Can anybody help me?

Comment: it won't use the margin because it's absolutely positionned. You can increase the top value. I don't see what exactly you are trying to do, so I can't answer more than that.

Comment: @BiAiB If I think it isn't a good idea to use `top` instead of `margin-top`

Comment: I think so, but you can't use it, in a position:absolute scenario. Maybe you should learn more about positionning of elements with CSS.

Comment: @BiAiB So how can I have elements with such position that jquery work fine with them?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand in 100% what you want to achieve, but your div #AdvancedPanel have margin-top 35px from div #urlpanel. If you give some height to div #AdvancedPanel then it looks good. Will you precise what you really want ?

Comment: If you click on the div that is after the input text the slide animate starts from top of the text input and you see a black line passing it and it's not beautiful!

Comment: You should change positioning on your div's. Try to use mostly position relative or static (default position). If you want to animate div which must be absolute, then put it into relative div. It would be then easier to animate. Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/instead/dzB6P

Comment: The sample is good but can you put it on the center of the page like the original? The problem is that I want that in the center

Comment: Then add width to #urlpanel. For example width: 430px; and then it is on the center